# Throwing NullPointerException when setting the Icon

Tags: java, maven, swing, nullpointerexception, imageicon

I'm currently learning about inserting an Image inside a JLabel. I'm following the documentation and instruction so far, but is still throwing a `NullPointerException`. Am I missing a syntax or something?

I'm gonna send a pic to better understand the location and names of the package and files. Sorry for sending a pic.

[image]

Exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:232)
> at com.mycompany.hotel_management_system.Log_In.(Log_In.java:28)
> at com.mycompany.hotel_management_system.Log_In.lambda$main$0(Log_In.java:329)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: Locate the directory that contains file `Log_In.class`. That directory should have a `Images` subdirectory. Make sure that the `Images` subdirectory contains file `212849.jpg`. Then try this code: `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Images/212849.jpg")));` Refer to [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Comment: Thank you! I followed all of the steps that you posted, and it worked. I did observe, though, that my `Images` folder was also deleted when I `Clean and Build` my project, so I always make a copy of it and paste it again after I `Clean and Build`, then I `Build` it again to ensure that my Images folder is included in my jar.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the image you are trying to load is not found at the expected location.

```
getClass().getResource(...)
```

should return some URL but I suspect that is null.
Divide the line into several, and check the result inbetween (via logging the URL, or just by comparing with null).

If that URL is null as I suspect, the resource you want to load does not exist. Add it to your classpath or correct the resource name.

Comment: or correct the path

Comment: In some cases, the problem can be solved with: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)`.
And in other cases, you have to start the path with a slash (/) and sometimes not. So you could try this out as well.